# Determine website content language

Tags: language-agnostic

For one of my applications I need to determine the language of an websites by getting it's content.

I would like to know your opinions about making a language determine script. Which methods you would use? Which scripting language? etc.

At this moment I wrote some code in PHP with a a few methods;

- Determine language by Content-Language meta tag
- Determine language by getting title,description,keywords and compare these agains wordlists such as english,dutch,german
- Determine language by html language tag'

  Determine language by getting all page content (separate words into array) and compare this against the wordlists by array_search (highest matched language array is language of content).

  Determine language by language headers

These steps I am taking now to determine the language, also exactly in this sequence. If one method succeed to determine the language, I quit the next functions.

This method is working but not always that accurate. Is there someone who can tell me more about things I can check on? Maybe a hole other way to check out the language (I don't want to use api's).

(at the end I need to set these languages to an MySql db).

Looking forward to hear some suggestions!

Thanks in advance.

Nick

Answer (score 0):

That will depends as long your text is..

First of all parse all html and extract only the text.

If it is long you can use a cheap method by looking only to stopwords. Get a list of stopwords for each language and figure out how many of them is into your text. You can get a nice list of stopwords in NLTK corpus(python) and take advantage of some good functions to tokenize sentences and words.

```
import nltk

ENGLISH_STOPWORDS = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))
NON_ENGLISH_STOPWORDS = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words()) - ENGLISH_STOPWORDS

STOPWORDS_DICT = {lang: set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words(lang)) for lang in  
                                            nltk.corpus.stopwords.fileids()}

def get_language(text):
    words = set(nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(text.lower()))
    return max(((lang, len(words & stopwords)) for lang, stopwords in STOPWORDS_DICT.items()), 
                                                                  key = lambda x: x[1])[0]
lang = get_language('This is my test text')
```

More explanation on http://www.algorithm.co.il/blogs/programming/python/cheap-language-detection-nltk/

If you want to go through python+nltk don't forget to download nltk corpus after installing.

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```